# Срезы словаря в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, словари, срез

Можно ли в питоне как-то брать срезы словаря? Есть очень большой словарь, из которого я хочу в цикле брать, допустим, по 500 элементов. Если со списком это можно запросто сделать чем-то вроде этого:

```
for i in range(len(l)//500):
    _ = l[500*i:500*(i+1)]
```

то в случае со словарем появится ошибка:

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

Появляется эта ошибка, я так понимаю, из-за того, что элементы словаря берутся по ключу. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Лучше не называйте переменные именами [встроенных функций](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#built-in-functions), таких как `list`, а то не сможете ими пользоваться, например `print(list("1234"))`

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо, поправил.

Comment: по пепу вместо _tmp пишут просто _

Comment: @Интик, исправил, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Словари не поддерживают срезы. Нужно привести словарь к списку, тогда этот код сработает.

Попробуйте:

```
data = dict()
items = list(data.items())

for i in range(len(items)//500):
    _tmp = items[500*i:500*(i+1)]
```

Comment: Попробовал. Самому такая мысль в голову приходила, но почему-то думал, что запихнет все вместе в один список, а не сформирует кортежи. .items() из головы вылетело. То, что нужно. Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 1):

Вот еще такой вариант:

```
from operator import itemgetter

d = {x: x**2 for x in range(50)}
itemgetter(*range(40, 50))(d) # 40 и 50 - границы среза
```

> (1600, 1681, 1764, 1849, 1936, 2025, 2116, 2209, 2304, 2401)